Data Factory Copy Activity - AzureFileLeaseConflictError
I have a copy activity which recursively copies a bunch a of xml files in a folder to another folder and deletes them after completion. The activity failed with the error below. Has anyone ever come across this error in ADF's copy activity? There's no documentation for the error!
Error code: AzureFileLeaseConflictError
Failure type: User configuration issue
Details: 
ErrorCode=AzureFileLeaseConflictError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=AzureFile lease has been acquired or not been released by other jobs. Path:path/to/file.xml,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The specified resource may be in use by an SMB client.,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common,'


Could you please provide your pipeline image?


ErrorCode=AzureFileLeaseConflictError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=AzureFile lease has been acquired or not been released by other jobs. Path:path/to/file.xml,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The specified resource may be in use by an SMB client.,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common,'

The file which you are trying to delete is acquire by lease or use by SMB client, that means file handles ore open on the specified path, when lease acquired on a file or SMB file handles are open then you are not able to delete the file, that may be the reason to get above error. when file leased as shown below:

Break the lease using below command in Azure Cloud Shell:
$headers = @{"x-ms-lease-action"= "break"}
$uri = "https://<accountName>.file.core.windows.net/<fileshareName>/<filePath>?comp=lease&<SASToken>"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Headers $headers -Uri $uri

Then lease will break on the file after running above command as shown below:

Along with that close open file handles using Azure Cloud Shell using below command:
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "mystorageacctname" -StorageAccountKey "<account key>"
Close-AzStorageFileHandle -ShareName "mysharename" -Path 'archive' -Recursive -CloseAll -Context $ctx -PassThru

Then you will be able to copy or delete the file successfully, without any error. For more information you can refer to this.

Hi, thanks for getting back. I should have mentioned that the source of these XML files is a File Share which is mounted on a Linux box where external applications place the XML files. I now realize that this might be the reason for the error, however I'd prefer an automated way to break the lease if possible.

If want to break the lease use above CLI script which I provided, otherwise use this RestAPI to break the lease.
